# Use find_package() on external project

Tags: cmake

I have an External project called `messages`. I am using ExternalProject_Add in order to fetch and build the project.

If i use `find_package(messages REQUIRED)` in top level CMakeLists.txt the `cmake ..` fails because it couldn't find the package installation files, which is logical as they are only build during `make` command invocation.

I am not sure, if there is way use find_package() on ExternalProjects. If so, please point me to an example.

Thanks
BhanuKiran

Comment: related to https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17735

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `ExternalProject` is supposed to work. You *cannot* `find_package(messages REQUIRED)` because it hasn't been built yet. `ExternalProject` merely creates the build steps necessary to build the subproject.

You have two options:

1. Use `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent` in place of `ExternalProject`. In this case, you don't need a `find_package` call. This effectively adds the sub-project to the main build and imports the subproject's targets.
2. Use *two* `ExternalProject` calls: one for `messages` and another for `main_project`, which depends on `messages`. If `messages` uses the `export(EXPORT)` function, you can point `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `messages_ROOT` to the build directory. Otherwise you'll need to run the install step for `messages` and set up an install prefix inside your build directory. Then the `find_project(messages REQUIRED)` call inside `main_project` will succeed. This will likely require re-structuring your build.

Generally speaking, `ExternalProject` is only useful for defining *super-builds*, which are chains of CMake builds that depend on one another. And super builds are only useful when you need completely different configure-time options, like different toolchains (eg. you're cross compiling, but need a code generator to run on the build machine). If that's not the case, prefer `FetchContent` or `add_subdirectory` with a git submodule.

It is best to use `FetchContent` with CMake 3.14+ since it adds the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` macro that cuts down on boilerplate.

Docs:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html

Comment: If the `messages` library uses the `export(EXPORT)` function to create a config file in the build directory the first external project call doesn't need to install the project if the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` for the second external project call is extended to include the build directory of the first project.

Comment: @Corristo - that is a good point, I'll add it to my answer

Comment: I'd like to point out that there are projects where FetchContent will _not_ work, such as libjpeg-turbo which does not support being added as a subdirectory, they explicitly state this in their Building.md

Answer (score 0):

Since I like keeping my CMake file agnostic on how I get my packages.

I was using `FetchContent` and added this file (`Findalib.cmake`):

```
if(NOT alib_POPULATED)
    set(alib_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL INTERNAL)
    set(alib_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL INTERNAL)
    set(alib_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL INTERNAL)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(alib)
endif()
set(alib_FOUND TRUE)
```

Then, in my CMake files:

```
find_package(alib REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my-executable PUBLIC alib::alib)
```

That way, packages are only declared in my file in which I declare dependencies, and I fetch them only if I try to find them.

Comment: The whole point of `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` is that you don't have to check the `proj_POPULATED` variable. There's also no module called `CMakeFetchContent`. It's just `FetchContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from to @Alex Reinking's answer, It is generally better to have less boiler plate, and use ExternalProject only for super-builds. However sometimes libraries do not support `FetchContent()` like @Blackclaws points out. That being said, it is somewhat better to use `ExternalProject_Add()` and this will be clear to the us as we keep developing C++ projects or our project gets larger.

Here is an alternate solution without `FetchContent_Declare()` or `find_package()`, albeit it is **not tested thoroughly**. It is possible to do this in pure CMake without external package managers. See the Details section below. What would be helpful to know beforehand are the targets (.lib/.dll/.so/.dylib) and include directories, namespaces, etc... that are exported by the *utility* which is returned by the `ExternalProject_Add()` command.

You can modify this example to include more of the available features from the [official docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

## TL;DR: Details

While configuring the project, we can use a dummy library to make cmake to trigger the build without causing errors with `ExternalProject_Add()` and pass in steps to create a `Debug` config of a target that we can use in our projects with a `Release` config of another target, and so on.

1. You need to specify the build and install args to the `ExternalProject_Add()` via the `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS` and not `CMAKE_ARGS` as they are superimposed by the transient args are carried forward (especially in IDEs like Visual Studio Code. If your project uses Debug build, but the ExternalProject specifies Release build)
2. Append to the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` the `Location/to/the/install/directory/of/your/target`
3. Create a temporary directory file(MAKE_DIRECTORY `Location/to/the/include/directory/of/your/target`).This will suppress the *Location is non-existent* errors at configure time.
4. The next is to create a dummy *imported interface library* that is a target that links into the your main executables. You need to set `IMPORTED_LOCATION` and `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and other properties this step. The docs are here, in [cmake-properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html).
5. Finally, `add_dependencies(dummy_target_name exported_target_name)` to remove errors being thrown in the output

(The returned target is called a utility in Visual Studio Code with the CMakeTools Extension. I will call it utility here as well. Not sure if it is called a utility in native cmake)

### Example

We will build [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) with `ExternalProject_Add()`.

#### Initial Project Structure

```
Project
    |
    |-src
    |   |-main.cpp
    |   
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |-cmake
    |   |-BuildExternalProject.cmake
    |   |-FindGLFW.cmake
```

Main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.2)
project("My_Project" VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
include(BuildExternalProject)
include(FindGlfw)

add_executable(exec src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(exec
    PUBLIC
        glfw_target
)
```

FindGLFW.cmake

```
BuildExternalProject(
    NAME            glfw
    LIB_NAME        glfw_target
    GIT_REPO        https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git
    GIT_TAG         3.3.8
    INSTALL_PATH    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external
    BUILD_TYPE      Release
    ARCHITECTURE    x64
)
```

cmake/BuildExternalProject.cmake:

```
include(ExternalProject)

macro(append_cmake_prefix_path)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${ARGN})
    string(REPLACE ";" "|" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
endmacro()

function(BuildExternalProject)
    set(one_value_args
        NAME            # name of directory in <INSTALL_DIR>/NAME"
        LIB_NAME        # For example, the glfw library needs us to link against the target glfw3 not glfw
        GIT_REPO        # URL : https://github.com/user/repo.git
        GIT_TAG         # Release tags: "3.3.8","2.3.2" ...
        INSTALL_PATH        # "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external" in this example
        BUILD_TYPE      # "Release", "Debug" ...
        ARCHITECTURE    # "x64","x86"...
    )
    set(multi_value_args
        EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS
        EXT_BUILD_ARGS
        EXT_INSTALL_ARGS
    )

    # Parse arguments.
    cmake_parse_arguments(
        _ARGS # Main prefix for parsed args
        "${options}"
        "${one_value_args}"
        "${multi_value_args}"
        ${ARGN} # Number of Args
    )

    # Set new path
    set(INSTALL_PATH_NEW_PREFIX ${_ARGS_INSTALL_PATH}/${_ARGS_ARCHITECTURE}-${_ARGS_BUILD_TYPE}/${_ARGS_NAME})

    set(INSTALL_PATH_LIB ${INSTALL_PATH_NEW_PREFIX}/lib)
    set(INSTALL_PATH_INCLUDE ${INSTALL_PATH_NEW_PREFIX}/include)

    set(_UTILITY_NAME ${_ARGS_NAME}_utility)

    ExternalProject_Add(
        ${_UTILITY_NAME}
        PREFIX ${_UTILITY_NAME}
        GIT_REPOSITORY ${_ARGS_GIT_REPO}
        GIT_TAG ${_ARGS_GIT_TAG}

        CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS # CMAKE_ARGS does not use the FORCE option, this is a problem especially in IDEs
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${_ARGS_BUILD_TYPE}"

        # This is where the install will
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${INSTALL_PATH_NEW_PREFIX}"

        # Addition parsed args
        ${_ARGS_EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS}

        # Commands to build
        BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <BINARY_DIR> --target install --config ${_ARGS_BUILD_TYPE}
        COMMAND ${_ARGS_EXT_BUILD_ARGS}

        # Commands to install
        INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <BINARY_DIR> --target install --config ${_ARGS_BUILD_TYPE}
        COMMAND ${_ARGS_EXT_INSTALL_ARGS}

        CONFIGURE_HANDLED_BY_BUILD ON # No config steps are passed
        BUILD_ALWAYS FALSE
        UPDATE_DISCONNECTED TRUE
    )

    # We append to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`
    append_cmake_prefix_path(${INSTALL_PATH_NEW_PREFIX})

    # We make the temporary directory
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${INSTALL_PATH_INCLUDE})

    # We make the new dummy imported library
    add_library(${_ARGS_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL ${_UTILITY_NAME})

    # Setup the include and libs/dlls,etc
    target_include_directories(${_ARGS_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE ${INSTALL_PATH_INCLUDE})
    target_link_libraries(${_ARGS_LIB_NAME} INTERFACE ${INSTALL_PATH_LIB}/*.lib)

    add_dependencies(${_ARGS_LIB_NAME} ${_UTILITY_NAME})
endfunction()
```

#### Final Project Structure

```
Project
    |
    |-src
    |   |-main.cpp
    |   
    |-external
    |   |-x64-Debug
    |   |   |-glfw                                          # Everything under this is auto generated
    |   |       |-include/GLFW/..         
    |   |       |-lib                     
    |   |       |   |-cmake/*Config.cmake; *.cmake          # This is where we need to point CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
    |   |       |   |                                       # so find_package() can find it you need it to in the future
    |   |       |   |-pkgconfig/*.pc                    
    |   |                            
    |   |-x64-Release                                          
    |       |-glfw                                          # Everything under this is auto generated
    |           |-include/GLFW/..         
    |           |-lib                     
    |           |   |-cmake/*Config.cmake; *.cmake          # This is where we need to point CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
    |           |   |                                       # so find_package() can find it you need it to in the future
    |           |   |-pkgconfig/*.pc
    |                                
    |   
    |
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |-cmake
    |   |-BuildExternalProject.cmake
    |   |-FindGLFW.cmake
```

## FetchContent_Declare vs ExternalProject_Add

1. Since `FetchContent_Declare()` makes the target available at configure time, and if the source is very large, you might not want to download or build all the libs at configure time, especially if your project needs only a few sub-targets from the external project. These parameters can be passed in as the optional args to the subproject via `ExternalProject_Add()`.
2. From the [docs of FetchContent_Declare](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html)

   > The *contentOptions* can be any of the download, update or patch options that the ExternalProject_Add() command understands. The configure, build, install and test steps are explicitly disabled and therefore options related to them will be **ignored**.
3. `ExternalProject_Add()` provides a larger set of options to run at configure, build, install, test, etc. It is a project in itself, and can help directly expose the fully or partially build binaries, libs, etc.

### Sources

1. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBptg3SHPGU&ab_channel=JeffersonAmstutz
3. https://github.com/jeffamstutz/superbuild_ospray
4. https://github.com/geospace-code/h5fortran/blob/main/cmake/hdf5.cmake
5. https://github.com/geospace-code/h5fortran/blob/main/cmake/h5fortran.cmake
6. https://github.com/deepmind/mujoco/blob/main/cmake/FindOrFetch.cmake