# cmake: Integrating FetchContent with find_package()

Tags: cmake

I am trying to understand the documentation from:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#integrating-with-find-package

So I tried a naive cmakelists.txt file such as:

```
% cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(p)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG        703bd9caab50b139428cea1aaff9974ebee5742e # release-1.10.0
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES gtest
)

# This will try calling find_package()
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
find_package(GTest)
message(${GTest_DIR})
```

If I run it, here is what I get:

```
$ cmake ..
[...]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/GTest
```

For some reason `find_package(GTest)` still tries to inspect the system for GTest instead of the one declared in the FetchContent code block.

What did I misunderstood from the cmake documentation ? I assumed the function `FetchContent`  was precisely meant for the case when user cannot use `ExternalProject` since it [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372317/use-find-package-on-external-project) integrate with `find_package`.

For reference:

```
% cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.1
```

Answer (score 5):

In very simple form: The option `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS` makes `FetchContent` to use results of `find_package`. But for make `find_package` to use results of `FetchContent`, you need to pass another option: `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE`.

---

Both `FetchContent` and `find_package` are intended to introduce a 3d-party project for use it during the build of main project. However, these two approaches uses different mechanisms:

1. `FetchContent` builds the 3d-party project from sources, alongside with the main one, but
2. `find_package` works with already installed 3d-party project.

CMake provides two "directions" of integration between `FetchContent` and `find_package`; each "direction" has its own, independent purposes.

### 1. Write a new project equally consuming a 3d-party project both in sources and installed.

Assume you write a project, which uses some 3d-party project. Assume you want to support two variants:

1. Use installed variant of the 3d-party project, if it is already available, or
2. Build the 3d-party project from sources alongside with your main project.

Parameter `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS` for `FetchContent_Declare` tells CMake to use `find_package` for locate installed 3d-party project, and, if it is available, do not build it from sources.

Such integration will work only if the main project uses the 3d-party project via interface, provided **both** by 3d-party project's sources and by `find_package`.

E.g. GTest's sources [create](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake#L155) ALIAS targets in namespace `GTest` (like `GTest::gtest_main`) and `find_package(GTest)` [creates](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/CMakeLists.txt#L103) IMPORTED targets with the same namespace. So, the outer project can safely link with `GTest::gtest_main` and this will work whenever GTest is already installed or is being built from sources.

### 2. Make an existing project to work with a 3d-party project built from sources

Assume you are creating a superproject, which combines several **already existed subprojects**. One of this subprojects executes `find_package` for the 3d-party project and uses its results. Assume you want that 3d-party project to be built from the sources.

Most of project-specific scripts, consumed by `find_package`, work only with the **installed packages** and doesn't work with the one which is currently being built. Some special power is needed..

#### Ignore 'find_package'

Parameter `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` for `FetchContent_Declare` means to **ignore** further `find_package` calls because the 3d-party project is being built from sources.

This approach works if the subproject uses only those results from `find_package`, which are available from the 3d-party project's sources too.
E.g. it will work if the subproject uses target `GTest::gtest_main` for link with. But it won't work if the subproject uses `GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES` variable, which is not set in the GTest sources.

#### Change a script executed by 'find_package'

But what if the subproject uses a part of interface, which is available only from `find_package` (and its project-specific script), but is not available from the sources of the 3d-party project? In that case it is possible to create a **fake script**, which will be executed by `find_package` instead of the normal one.

```
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_REDIRECTS_DIR}/gtest-extra.cmake
[=[
  set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES GTest::gtest_main)
]=])
```

Lines between `[=[` and `]=]` becomes part of the created script, which defines
`GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES` variable suitable for link in a subproject.

(Note, that the file `gtest-extra.cmake` has a sence only when `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` parameter has been specified for `FetchContent_Declare`.)